# Is "year" required for "@online" natbib entry?

Tags: natbib

Example:
https://github.com/justinacolmena/bor/tree/ef5db2002a12e7994d98e5a13f794bec0c32d411

**bor.tex**

```
...
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
...
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
...
\bibliography{bor}{}
```

**bor.bib**

```
@online{lexilogos-fi,
        title={{Lexilogos Finnish Dictionary}},
        url={http://www.lexilogos.com/english/finnish_dictionary.htm}
}
```

**bor.pdf**

> [5] Lexilogos Finnish Dictionary, . URL http://www.lexilogos.com/english/finnish_dictionary.htm.

This is for an informal document. I just want a link in the bibliography, not a full-blown formal academic citation.

Note the comma, extra space (for the year even though not specified) and period after the title in the resulting bibliography entry. This error does not *always* occur, only sporadically and unpredictably.

```
[justina@localhost ~]$ dnf info --installed texlive
Installed Packages
Name         : texlive
Epoch        : 6
Version      : 2016
Release      : 33.20160520.fc26.1
Arch         : x86_64
...
```

I would gladly use a more modern package such as `biblatex`, but then i run into the same error, and other formatting issues that go against my preferred style.

Answer (score 2):

The correct entry type for the usage with `bibtex` is `misc`; the entry `online` can be used with `biblatex`/`biber`.

The following MWE compiles without errors, only 4 warnings (okay, because in the two entrys are missing fields!):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@misc{lexilogos-fi,
  title={{Lexilogos Finnish Dictionary}},
  url={http://www.lexilogos.com/english/finnish_dictionary.htm}
}
@misc{test,
  url={http://www.lexilogos.com/english/finnish_dictionary.htm}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} %
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

BTW: I'm running an current MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: I have had the same problem with "@misc" as I've had with "@online" -- I'm not necessarily stuck on it, but I am using `natbib`, not at the moment `bibtex`, `biblatex`, or `biber`. I've had problems with all these packages with an unavoidable period that appears outside of a closing parenthesis or quotation marks, or even after a question mark or exclamation point.